# PHP SimpleXMLElement, get element and its children as XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<Book>
    <bookname>thename</bookname>
    <chapters>
        <chapter>
            <name>chapter1</name>
        </chapter>
         <chapter>
            <name>chapter2</name>
        </chapter>
    </chapters>
</Book>
```

How can I get an XML as follows:

```
    <chapters>
        <chapter>
            <name>chapter1</name>
        </chapter>
         <chapter>
            <name>chapter2</name>
        </chapter>
    </chapters>
```

One way is to manually remove unwanted elements e.g

```
$resultXML = new SimpleXMLElement($inputXML);
unset($resultXML->bookname);
$resultXML = $resultXML->asXml();
echo format_result($resultXML,$format);
```

But if I have a large XML with many unwanted notes, this is tedious. Any idea who to extract the required element using its name?

Comment: `$resultXML->chapters->asXml()` …?

Comment: @CBroe It was too simple to be true! Could you create an answer so that I can vote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub-nodes of your XML are themselves SimpleXMLElements – so you can just call the axXml method on them as well.

Since you only have one `chapters` node in your XML, simply

```
$resultXML->chapters->asXml()
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
<?php

$inputXML ="
<Book>
    <bookname>thename</bookname>
    <chapters>
        <chapter>
            <name>chapter1</name>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <name>chapter2</name>
        </chapter>
    </chapters>
</Book>
";

/* Load from file:
$parseXML = simplexml_load_file( $fileURL );
*/
$parseXML = simplexml_load_string( $inputXML );
$chapters = $parseXML->chapters->asXML();

echo $chapters;

?>
```

Note: Your xml must be well-formated, currently your `<Book>` has no closing tag.